# Prove that cyclic index of this operation can be expressed by formula

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be disjoint finite sets and let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be, respectively, some groups of permutations of this sets. Direct sum $G_1 \bigotimes G_2$ acts on $T_1 \cup T_2$:

$$
\langle g_1,g_2 \rangle t =
\begin{cases}
g_1 t&\text{if }t \in T_1,\\
g_2 t&\text{if } t \in T_2.
\end{cases}
$$

Prove that cyclic index of this operation can be expressed by the formula: 
$$
I_{G_1 \bigotimes G_2}=I_{G_1}I_{G_2}
$$

Comment: (i) for binary tensor products, use `\otimes` not `\bigotimes`, (ii) you're talking about the direct sum, not tensor product, so use `\oplus` rather than `\otimes` (and, in case it bears saying, not `\bigoplus`).

Comment: Are you talking about the cycle index? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cycle index of a permutation group is a sum of monomials associated to the elements of the group.

Let $m_g$ be the monomial associated to $g\in G$. Show that for $(g_1,g_2)\in G_1\times G_2$ we have the relation $m_{(g_1,g_2)}=m_{g_1}m_{g_2}$. Do you see how to leverage this for the cycle index relation?